# question on drawing v-t, x-t and a-t graphs

Tags: physics

[image]

can anyone draw pictures of the x-t, v-t, and a-t graphs..

i think i know how to do it but I want to make sure. For example for the first question, my x-t graph will just have positive slope starting from origin, my vt graph will have a slope of 0 above the x-axis, and the a-t graph will have slope 0 on the origin. is this correct? can someone show me with some drawings so i can better visualize it please?

Comment: Personally, I would just solve the problem and then draw the function, but that's just me liking algebra over waving my hands.

Comment: This is a physics question, not a math question. Questions to ask yourself: What is the initial value? Is the value increasing or decreasing? Is it linear?